# SequenceType Generator Generic Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm having some issues trying to run this code, I found couple examples using the same code but I get compiler error

***Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "ExpSwift.SearchResults.generate () -> Swift.IndexingGenerator<[A]>", referenced from:
      ExpSwift_Example.ViewController.(viewDidLoad () -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #3) in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

here is my code class

```
public final class SearchResults<T> {

var results = [T]();
let total: Int64

required public init?(results: [T], total: Int64) {
    self.results = results
    self.total = total
}

public func getResults() -> [T] {
    return self.results
}

public func getTotal() -> Int64 {
    return self.total
}

}


extension SearchResults : SequenceType {
   public func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<Array<T>> {
    return results.generate()
   }
}
```

and then calling this with Alamofire

```
ExpSwift.findLocations(["limit":10, "skip":0, "sort":"name"]).then { (locations: SearchResults<Location>) -> Void in
            for location:Location in locations{
                debugPrint(location.get("name"))
            }

            }.error { error in
                debugPrint(error)
        }
```

Comment: That code compiles without problems in my Xcode 7.3.1, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm doing this  for location:Location in locations
                {                    debugPrint(location.get("name"))

                } I'm also using xcode 7.3.1

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm on 7.3.1, maybe something with cocoapods?? I don't know but it fails only when I add the for with the location object

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is just something with cocoapods or Xcdoe, the solution for me was just update Xcode 8 and download Xcode 7.3 . If I work with Xcode 7.3 fix the issue with the compiler. I try several times to build and after couple times it works.